# ExtJS 4.2 - 'value' under new FieldSet not displaying

Tags: extjs, combobox

There's a weird issue I'm having displaying existing values from a callback. I have no problems with other values from other declared `FieldSet` forms, and both are identical in structure.

My `initComponent` does a simple rendering of a newly added component:

```
initComponent: function() {
  var me = this;
  mappedSegments = ['something', 'something1'],
    mappedText = '';
  var cData = [];

  Ext.getStore('CustomerSegments').each(function(data, key) {
    cData.push({
      name: data.get('name'),
      id: data.get('id')
    });
  });

  var result = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    autoDestroy: true,
    fields: ['name', 'id'],
    data: cData
  });

  me.callParent();

  mappedText = mappedSegments.toString().replace(/,/g, ', ');

  console.log(mappedText); // I get the expected values here
  me.add({
    xtype: 'boxselect',
    layout: 'hbox',
    store: result,
    name: 'segments',
    value: mappedText, // but are not displaying here
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'name',
    allowBlank: true,
    width: 353,
    height: 65,
    cls: 'customer-segments-boxselect',
    style: {
      margin: '5px 0 5px 0'
    }
  });
}
```

Note that `boxselect` is a third party component plugin that converts comboboxes into multiselect fields. I have tested this on a normal combobox, and the issue persist.

What am I missing here? This can't be an asynchronous thing, can it? Because this perfectly works fine on other identical `Ext.form.FieldSet`s.

Comment: Please provide a fiddle as an example.

Comment: Is the store (Ext.getStore('CustomerSegments')) loaded at this time?

Comment: Yes. I figured out a workaround. Seems like the data is loading correctly, but the render is loading before it catches the data to display on it. I placed the loaded data on a `beforerender` instead of `initComponent`.